# Error when debugging Flutter app in VSCode

Tags: flutter, debugging, visual-studio-code

When I try to debug my Flutter app in **VSCode** it shows an error.

I debug using **Huawei Y5 Prime 2018** **(DRA-LX2)**

Log:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on DRA LX2 in debug mode...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Failed to extract manifest from APK: ProcessException: The command failed
Command: C:\Users\Mohammed\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.3\aapt dump 
xmltree D:\dicee-flutter\build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk AndroidManifest.xml.
Exception: Problem building Android application: see above error(s).
Exited (sigterm)
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try this command

`flutter clean`